# I'm getting a "type error: next is not a function" in my auth middleware

Tags: node.js, express

```
const auth = asyncWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {

    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

    if(!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Access denied! No token' })

    const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY);

    req.user = await User.findOne({_id: decodedData._id })

    next();
})
```

This is an authentication middleware to give access to only authorised users to perform certain tasks.

Comment: have you tried seeing what `next` is? How are you calling this function?

Comment: Where does `asyncWrapper` come from?

Comment: asyncWrapper is a global try catch function for which a function is passed as a parameter and it handles any promise rejections.

Comment: You're not posting enough context (for instance, there's a possibility the issue exists in `asyncWrapper` but you're not showing it)